# Getting stuck in a logic statement

Tags: bash, logic

I'm writing a BASH script to purge the cache from a web server. The script is designed to take arguments from positional parameters. "ShellCheck.net" is telling me that my script is functionally correct, but when I test it I'm getting error where I shouldn't ... so I thought I'd ask for some folks to put fresh eyes on it.  Take a look, I'll continue below and describe my problem:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    #
    # Verify the user running is root, if not, fail.
    if [[ "$UID" -ne "0" ]]; #added-1438279711
        then
            echo 'Only ROOT may run this script.';
            exit 1;
    fi
    #
    # Set the variables
    BASE="/path/to/folder/foo/bar/" #added-1438279711
    DOMAINOPT="$1" #added 1438451428
    PATHOPT="$2" #added 1438451428
    #
    # Define Functions
    function usage() { #added-1438382631
        echo -en "Proper Usage:\n\n"
        echo -en "\tSpecify the domain to be used\n"
        echo -en "\tUsage: \"cleancache.sh abc.com\"\n"
        echo -en "\t\tNote: This option will search for files and folders, recursively, within the domain folder, and remove them.\n\n"
        echo -en "\tSpecify the URI you'd like to act upon within the domain\n"
        echo -en "\tUsage: \"cleancache.sh abc.com /path/to/folder/\"\n"
        echo -en "\t\tNote: This option will search for files and folders, recursively,\n\t\twithin the specified path, and remove them. Removing a single file is not currently supported with this script.\n\n"
    }
    #
    # Validate the input
    if [[ ! -z "$DOMAINOPT" ]] && [[ "$DOMAINOPT" != "^[A-Za-z0-9-]*[\.][a-z]*$" ]] #added-1438462778
        then
            clear
            echo -en "Please follow the proper format for the DOMAIN option\n\n"
            usage
            exit 1
    elif [[ ! -z "$DOMAINOPT" ]] && [[ "$DOMAINOPT" = "^[A-Za-z0-9-]*[\.][a-z]*$" ]]
        then
            DOMAINOPT="$DOMAINOPT"
    else
        clear
        echo -en "Please enter a domain!\n\n"
        usage
        exit 1
    fi
    if [[ ! -z "$PATHOPT" ]] && [[ "$PATHOPT" != "^[\/][\S]*[\/]$" ]] #added-1438456371
        then
            clear
            echo "Please follow the proper format for the PATH option"
            usage
            exit 1
    elif [[ ! -z "$PATHOPT" ]] && [[ "$PATHOPT" = "^[\/][\S]*[\/]$" ]]
        then
            PATHOPT="$PATHOPT"
    else
        echo ""
    fi
    #
    # Doing Stuff
    if [[ "$#" -gt "2" ]]
        then
            echo -en "Too many arguments!\n\n"
            usage
            exit 1
    elif [[ "$#" -eq "2" ]]
        then
            echo "Purging Cache in \"$BASE$DOMAINOPT$PATHOPT\""
            find "$BASE""$DOMAINOPT""$PATHOPT" -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
            find "$BASE""$DOMAINOPT""$PATHOPT" -type f -exec rm -f {} \;
            echo "Purging Complete"
            exit 0
    else
        echo "Purging Cache in \"$BASE$DOMAINOPT\""
        find "$BASE" -type d -name "$DOMAINOPT" -exec rm -rf {} \;
        mkdir -p "$BASE$DOMAINOPT" && chown apache:apache "$BASE$DOMAINOPT" && chmod 755 "$BASE$DOMAINOPT"
        echo "Purging Complete!"
        echo "Creating \".stat\" file"
        echo "" > "$BASE""$DOMAINOPT""/.stat"
            if [[ -f "$BASE""$DOMAINOPT""/.stat" ]] #added-1438387045
                then
                    echo "$BASE$DOMAINOPT/.stat file created!"
            fi
    fi
    echo "All Operations Complete, exiting now!"
```

Everything responds normally if you run the script without any arguments (Please enter a domain), It responds normally if you try to enter a path before a domain ... but when I do it correctly, when I type: "cleancache.sh abc.com", I get an error like i haven't met the required pattern ("Please follow the proper format for the DOMAIN option") ... when that is exactly write! ... I don't understand what I'm missing, been banging my head all day, no joy.

PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to match a regex:

```
[[ "$DOMAINOPT" =~ ^[A-Za-z0-9-]*[\.][a-z]*$ ]]
```

or this:

```
[[ ! "$DOMAINOPT" =~ ^[A-Za-z0-9-]*[\.][a-z]*$ ]]
```

Don't quote the regex.

Comment: THAT WAS IT, EXACTLY.  LOL, only spent 12 hours yesterday troubleshooting everything BUT that!  Urgh!  Thanks!  I've tried to Google it, to no avail, but what does "=~" do and how is it different than "="?  Also, why was quoting my Regex wrong?

Comment: With `=` you can compare two exact matching strings. With `=~` the string on the right is considered an extended regular expression. The regex syntax must not have quotes when used with `[[ ]]`.